# How to make Irssi automatically send a message to a username on connecting to a specific server?

Tags: gnupg, irc, irssi

I want Irssi to automatically message NickServ with the message "CONFIRM <PASSWORD HERE>" whenever I connect to irc.rizon.net, and I want it to get the password from a gpg-encrypted file. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm a bit unfamiliar with Irssi limitations, but I believe you may be able to accomplish this with a combination of the `autosendcmd` option of `/network add` and `/exec` to pull the information from your file.

Comment: Unfortunately, /EXEC cannot use a interactive terminal, but I need to input the encryption password to gpg and I cannot risk storing the gpg password in plaintext. gpg terminates with return code 2 with the error message `no tty`

Comment: There is an `-interactive` flag to `/exec`, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: I tried using `-interactive` but it returns the same error.